# Picasso Library Data Uri Scheme base64

Tags: base64, picasso

I need some help on implementing a data uri scheme image decoder, I get a url with a string containing image encoded in base64
with something like this: :
"data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJ.....TY3OD=="

**Is there an existing decoder or an example on how to implement it in picasso?**

I'm currently using a modified version of the "Displaying Bitmaps Efficiently" example, but the caching is really basic.

Thanks in Advance.
Roberto.